# How to know the class file names (including inner classes) that will generate after compiling a given java file?

Tags: java

I am working on some kind of software delivery tool. For one of its task the program needs to find the class file names which will generate after compiling any given java file.

I need some kind of parsing library/approach which can detect all inner 
classes(named as well as anonymous)  too.

e.g.: If input file contains below code. Our program should generate output as: SampleClass1.class, SampleClass1$Data.class, SampleClass1$1.class

```
package com.aci.uob.patchmanifest.helper.testapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class SampleClass1 {
    public static String CONSTANT_ATTR = "Sample String Constant";

    int attr;
    boolean b;

    private class Data implements Comparable<Data>{
        String val="--";

        public Data(String val) {
            super();
            this.val = val;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Data o) {
            return this.val.compareTo(o.val);
        }

    }

    public SampleClass1(int attr, boolean b) {
        super();
        System.out.println("this is a sample constructor");
        this.attr = attr;
        this.b = b;
    }


    private void runInnerClasses(){
        List<Data> list=new ArrayList<Data>();

        list.add(new Data("Hello"));
        list.add(new Data("World"));
        list.add(new Data("20"));
        list.add(new Data("100"));
        list.add(new Data(" Hello"));

        Collections.sort(list);

        printList(list);

        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Data>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Data o1, Data o2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return o1.val.trim().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.val.trim());
            }

        });


    }


    private void printList(List<Data> list) {
        for(Data d: list)
            System.out.println(d.val);
    }
}
```

Comment: What names does the compiler currently generate?

Comment: Yes @TimBiegeleisen, I have to find what names the java compiler generates when a java file is compiled.

Comment: Back to my question, what names do you get?  I don't think it will be easy or desirable to try to change how the compiler names inner classes.

Comment: No, I don't want to change the name of class files. I need the names of class files to pass on to some other modules which will use it for different purposes. I could have compiled the java file and then read the generated *.class file names; but I don't have dependent classes and thus it will give me compile error with that approach.

Answer (score 0):

If your program are running under Eclipse, [JDT API](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2FICompilationUnit.html)(`org.eclipse.jdt.core` plugin) is a choice. Here is a example:

```
IJavaElement ele = JavaCore.create(ifile);
if (ele instanceof ICompilationUnit) {
    IType[] czs = ((ICompilationUnit)ele).getAllTypes();
    for (int i = 0; i < czs.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(czs[i].getTypeQualifiedName());
        //IType.getFullyQualifiedName() will return value include package name
        IMethod[] ims = czs[i].getMethods();
        for (int j = 0; j < ims.length; j++) {
            IJavaElement[] childs = ims[j].getChildren();
            //find anonymous type inside Method
            for (int k = 0; k < childs.length; k++) {
                if (childs[k] instanceof IType) {
                    System.err.println(((IType)childs[k]).getTypeQualifiedName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output example:

> SampleClass1
>
> SampleClass1$Data
>
> SampleClass1$1

The JDT core API doesn't handle naming of anonymous types.
If `private void printList(List list)` also include a anonymous type.
The API also return **SampleClass1$1**.

You may also need `czs[i].getFields()` to find anonymous type inside Field. If SampleClass1 declare a class variable like:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run(){};
};
```

Comment: Thanks @beckyang ! Your answer is very explanatory, but I am looking for a different solution. I have to run this program independently outside any IDE. The program will only receive a java file (or its full text content) and it should generate class file names that will generate after compilation by java compiler.

Comment: I find a useful article: [a complete standalone example of ASTParser](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/01/a-complete-standalone-example-of-astparser). Using JDT API outside Eclipse is not a problem.